# D7: Get terms from node and display other nodes with same term in block?

Tags: taxonomy-terms, blocks, views

I have a node that has terms:

Artist1

And need a block to show all the other nodes that has Artist1 as a term

I tried this solution [Display the title of related nodes from taxonomy in block](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/654/display-the-title-of-related-nodes-from-taxonomy-in-block)

I set it to "Provide a default argument", and configured that to use the nid of the node being viewed... and nothing

this seems simple but been working at it for hours now.

Answer (score 1):

Try this module - https://drupal.org/project/views_arguments_extras
This allows you to select a field from the current node as a contextual filter. 
Enable this module.
Create a  new view, block display, and the chose the relevant field as the contextual filter.
Configure the view as per your requirement and show the block on your node page. It should work.

Answer (score 0):

You need a block view that accepts a term (from your node) as argument. I'm not sure how you'd best pass the term as argument to the view block but here's a possible solution: [Passing Arguments to block in 7.x Views](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/4031/passing-arguments-to-block-in-7-x-views)

Answer (score 0):

This answer works in Views version 2 or higher. First you need to install Views attach ( http://drupal.org/project/views_attach ). Please read about Views attach before proceeding further. Views attach is best explained by this video http://mustardseedmedia.com/podcast/episode37

Now we get to Views attach. Please enable the views attach module before proceeding. Essentially `Views attach` attaches a view at the end of the node. In our case our view will be a listing of other articles with the same term.

We will essentially need to "pass" the taxonomy term of the node to the view. Let the name of your Vocabulary be called `MyVocab`.

Steps to make the view.

1. Lets call the view `display_other_articles_with_same_taxonomy`.
2. Add a display of type `Node Content` (available after enabling Views attach). This is a display just like block and page displays but with special ability of attaching itself to the node.

Make the following settings in the `Node Content Display`

```
Node content settings
Node types: [select the content types you are interested in seeing the list of nodes with same taxonomy term]
Build modes: Teaser, Full node
Arguments: token
Show title: No
```

You should select `Use tokens from the node the view is attached to` under Arguments. Let the token be `[term-id]` This is the **"ID of top taxonomy term"**. This is very important!! Essentially you are going to be passing the taxonomy term of the node from the `MyVocab` (See http://groups.drupal.org/node/11788#comment-38332). If it has the lowest weight, the taxonomy vocabulary will be the first vocabulary in the taxonomy section of your node edit form. Add an argument `Taxonomy: Term Id`.

Add the fields you are interested in e.g. `Node: Title`. Make sure the `Node: Title` is made into a hyperlink by ticking `Link this field to its Node`

So what this view is going to do is:

1. Take the taxonomy term from the `MyVocab` vocabulary in the Node that is currently being viewed
2. Pass that as argument to the view `display_other_articles_with_same_taxonomy`
3. List all the nodes that have the same taxonomy term as the node being displayed.

Thats it!

If you're using Views 3 (currently at alpha3 at the time of writing) *and* you want a block (right now the articles have same taxonomy term come at the end of node body) you can do it in the following fashion:

1. Forget about views attach... its not required
2. Add a block view. It should contain the same argument, fields and filters as the instructions above for the `Node Content` display.
3. You need to modify the settings for the argument `Taxononomy: Term Id` just slightly: Under `Action to take if argument is not present:` choose `[x] Provide Default Argument`. Choose `[x] Taxonomy Term ID from URL`. Now make sure `[] Load default argument from term page` is unselected and `[x] Load default argument from node page, thats good for related taxonomy blocks.` Also `[x]Limit terms by vocabulary` and choose the `Series` vocabulary.
4. Make sure you name the block and put it in the appropriate region.

**Note:** This answer is subset of the answer I provided at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3895213/how-to-just-show-nodequeue-block-on-included-nodes/3909670#3909670 In that scenario the requirement was that the related articles are explicitly selected and listed in a particular order. Its a little more complex and uses Nodequeues which we don't need here at all.

Answer (score 0):

Not advisable, but as an option you can use php codes inside the views contextual filters, code something like below.

Assuming this view block has to be placed with a node, so taking arg(1) as nid.

```
  $node = node_load(arg(1));
  if($node && isset($node->your_taxonomy_field_name[LANGUAGE_NONE])) {
      foreach($node->your_taxonomy_field_name[LANGUAGE_NONE] as $term) {
          $terms[] = $term['tid'];
      }
      return implode('+',$terms);
  }
  else {
      return;
  }
```